# JQuery onclick handler syntax

Tags: jquery, onclick, event-handling

While posting another question on SO, I noticed an ad on the side which ran like this:

```
$('#apply-now').on('click', () => {new GreatCareer()});
/* Invoke and submit your resume */
```

Now, that bit with `() => {new GreatCareer()}` is new to me. I had seen anonymous or named functions in that place. What does this syntax mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new ECMAScript 6 [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Syntax:

```
    var a = [
      "Hydrogen",
      "Helium",
      "Lithium",
      "Beryl­lium"
    ];

    // initial sytax
    var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

    // arrow function sytax
    var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

> // A function with no parameters requires parentheses: () => {
>   statements }

so the `()` represent empty paramters of the function and as per the new syntax, the `function` keyword is ommitted.

SO `$('#apply-now').on('click', () => {new GreatCareer()});`

implies

`$('#apply-now').on('click', function(){ return new GreatCareer(); });`

Answer (score 0):

This is lambda notation, just another way to define a function.

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions